# Laravel required if doesnt skip on false

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I use `required_if:field,value` with another validation, it doesn't skip other validation:

```
[
'admin' => ['sometimes','in:0,1']
'something' => ['required_if:admin,1','min:6']
]
```

If admin is 1 everything is fine, if admin is 0 I keep getting 422 for min:6 rule. Why isn't this skipped?
also tried adding sometimes as well but still doesn't skip other rules

For some reason when I use array rules `['rule1','rule2']` it does not work but if I use `'rule1|rule2'` it does work..

Comment: When you validate, it's going to validate all of the rules. If you want it to stop after the first failed rule, then you can use [bail](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#stopping-on-first-validation-failure)

Comment: For some reason when I use array rules ['rule1','rule2'] it does not work but if I use 'rule1|rule2' it does work..